# The volume of an N-dimensional ball in Euclidean space with radius that grows with N

Tags: geometry, asymptotics, volume, spheres

Let $V_N(R_N)$ denote the volume of an $N$-dimensional ball in $\mathbf{R}^N$ with radius $R_N$. Suppose $R_N = O(\sqrt{N})$. Is it possible to show that $V_N = o(1)$? What about if $R_N = O(N)$?

Comment: You use $N$ for both the dimension and the radius.  Is that what you intended? Also a sphere is the surface and a ball is the contents.  When you say volume that seems to mean contents.  Please check.  The volume of a ball in $N$ space is proportional to $R^N$, but if you are increasing the dimension as well it is not really fair to compare the $N-$volumes as they are dimensionally different.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes the radius of the ball grows as the dimension of the space grows. I'm interested in whether the Lebesgue measure of the ball vanishes.

Comment: Have you looked up the volume of an [$N-$ ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere)?

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes. For example, the volume of an n-ball with unit radius decreases to zero as the dimension grows. But what if the radius of the ball also increased?

Comment: Have you tried applying Stirling's formula to [the volume formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#The_volume) to approximate the Gamma function there?